# Drupal 7 background image fixed without scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, drupal

In a Drupal 7 website, want to have background image fixed without scrolling.
Used overflow-y:hidden to make it, but only working in Firefox.
    body {
        overflow-y:hidden;
    }
The overflow-y seems not working in other browsers.

Is there other way like overflow-y to make background image fixed without scrolling for all browsers?

Comment: Do you mean that you want your background to remain stationary while you scroll the website up and down?

Comment: Can you please explain a little better what you mean? Do you want the image to move with the page as you scroll? Do you want it to stay in one exact spot even if you scroll? Or do you want something different? Also, could you share your HTML and a bit more CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
body { 
     background: url('images/bodybg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

This works for me.